# IOS programming on Windows system

Tags: windows, ios

I'm interested in learning IOS programming but at the moment i do not have access to a Macintosh system. Just wondering if there is an equivalent of IOS SDK for Windows? I do have an iphone though :)

Comment: Nope. AFAIX, you need XCode from Apple, which only runs on MacOS X+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/) which is a cross-platform objective-c API that you can work with on windows. Not exactly the same, but you can at least get your feet wet in working with objective-c and cocoa-like objects.

Answer (score 3):

You need a Mac to get started with iOS development. However, you could google "Hackintosh"  and try to install Mac OSX on your windows laptop, which will enable you to install XCode and later iOS Development.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are indeed development platforms on windows for the iPhone and iPad. The usually do not support the native iOS language: [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c). However, most of them to allow you to build and or deploy onto iOS through some method or other. Here are a few recommendations:

- **DragonFire SDK**. It is currently only for game development, but if you're really determined you can make a non-game app simply by adding UI elements programmatically (however this can be very painful). Dragon Fire SDK runs on Windows XP, Vista and 7. It costs a bit of money to be get full features from the SDK and submit to the AppStore. Here is the link: http://www.dragonfiresdk.com I have used it before, it works wonders. You can develop for the iPhone or iPad and it's all in C/C++. It comes with examples and help files too.
- **Stencyl**. This is a simple and easy to use Game IDE that allows you to deploy your 2D games onto multiple platforms: Windows, Mac OSX, iOS, etc. STencyl requires no coding, however if you pay for the full version you can add your own [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) or [flash](/questions/tagged/flash) code. Here's the link: http://www.stencyl.com
- **Unity**. Unity 3D is a *very* complex and *very high end* (in other words, expensive) game IDE and engine that lets you build 3D games for any platform (almost any, ex. iOS, OSX, Windows, Xbox, Wii, Playstation, Android, Linux). Unity costs (on the cheaper end) $1500... so this is probably not the best solution if you don't have the money to buy a Mac which is around the same price. However, if you're looking for one of the best Game Engines and IDEs with options to distribute to literally every platform, you may want to check it out: http://unity3d.com

All in all, DragonFire SDK is probably your best bet. It gives you the most flexibility on your PC for the price and it doesn't take a huge learning curve. I tried DragonFire before getting my Mac or knowing about iOS Development. And I had a simple guitar app up and running with DragonFire in an hour or so using my prior C++ knowledge.

If you aren't looking for a development platform, try out [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org) to get a basic understanding of Obj-C. You could also look into building a "Hackintosh".

Answer (score 1):

The best way to build iOS applications on a Windows machine is with the Adobe AIR packager for iOS.  No, it isn't programming with the iOS SDK - but the current best-selling application in the App Store games category (Mechanarium) was built with it.

http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/06/adobe-air-2-7-now-available-ios-apps-4x-faster.html